# ExecuteOrDelayUntilScript not working - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, jquery

I have written a function to scroll a Gannt chart to today's date.

The sharepoint file jsgrid.js is registered SOD during init.js and includes the function "ScrollGanttToDate", which I need in my function.

I entered the script below in a script editor webpart, and get the error "Unable to get value of the property 'ScrollGanttToDate': object is null or undefined". The script jsgrid.js has also not loaded at this point.

My question is, why is the execution of my function not being delayed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ScrollGanttToToday(),'jsgrid.js');
   function ScrollGanttToToday(){
     $("div [id$='_ListViewWebPartJSGrid']")[0].jsgrid.ScrollGanttToDate(new Date());
   }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `()` while calling the function. Replace below line

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ScrollGanttToToday(),'jsgrid.js');
```

with

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ScrollGanttToToday,'jsgrid.js');
```